# How to find the two closest points on two Ellipsoids?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

An ellipsoid has the general equation of:

[image]

*[Centered at (x, y, z) = (d, e, f)]*

How would you find one point on each ellipsoid such that the distance between these two points is the shortest distance possible between these two ellipsoids.

The only way i can up with is finding the line that passes through each of the ellipsoid's centers, then finding at what points the line intercepts each ellipsoid.

However I don't believe that this works for every case.

Comment: Not an easy task. Your proposed approach will usually not give the correct answer. Check "Finding the distance between ellipsoids", Tamasyan et al. 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that can work to compute the closest points between ellipsoids. It is a closed form solution i.e., there is no need to solve an optimization problem. It only needs a fairly simple linear algebra. I think it should work but I haven't test it. I will try to test it once I have some time however I post it here now so you can test on your own and confirm whether it works or not.

**Transforming Ellipsoids to Spheres Forth and Back**

We can always transform an ellipsoid into a sphere. An ellipsoid has a center point O and three "radius" or semi-axes, which can be visualized as three orthogonal vectors: A1, A2 and A3. We can apply a non-uniform scaling transformation to all semi-axes vectors to make them equal size, so we get a sphere.

We define an ellipsoid "E" by its center O, which is a 3d point and its three semi-axes A1, A2 and A3, which are also 3d vectors. We can assume, without loss of generality, that the three axes forms a right handed coordinate system where the A3 direction is given by the cross product of A1 and A2 semi-axes A1 × A2 scaled to get A3's length.

For now suppose there is a linear function M that can be used to transform (scale) an ellipsoid E into a sphere S, with radius equal to the smaller axis, by applying M to ellipsoid's semi-axes A1, A2 and A3 and to the ellipsoid's center O.

Notice that the eliipsoid's center O and ellipsoid's smaller vector A3 are not changed by M. So M(A3) = A3 and M(O) = O. That means that the sphere S has the same orientation and is at the same position C than the ellipsoid E. The linear function M has a corresponding inverse function M^-1 so we can transform back the vectors of the sphere S to get the original ellipsoid E.

Going back to the problem, we have two ellipsoids: E1 and E2. We can transform them using function M1 which will transform E1 into the sphere S1 and E2 into other ellipsoid E2'. Lets call this set of transformed objects "the S1 space". We can send S1 and E2' back to orinial space using M1^-1. We can compute the closest points in S1 space more easily as this is a simpler problem i.e., find closest points of S1 and E2'.

Now we can focus on a related sub-problem: find the closest point on ellipsoid E2'.

**Closest point on ellipsoid E2'**

Given a point C, which is the center of S1, we want to find the closest point on ellipsoid E2' to the point C.

To do that we apply M2' to transform the ellipsoid E2' into the sphere S2' and also apply M2' to C to get C' which is now in S2' space.

The closest point in S2' surface to C' is given by:

Q'' = O2' + (C' - O2') * |S2'| / |C' - O2'|

Where O2' is the center point of S2' and |S2'| is the radius of S2'.

The closest point on ellipsoid E2' is the point Q' given by:

Q' = M2'^-1 Q''

**Closest point on ellipsoid E1**

Now having Q' we can know the closest point from Q' to S1. Since S1 is a sphere we follow the same logic:

P' = C + (Q' - C) * |S1| / |Q' - C|

Where C is the center point of S1 and |S1| is the radius of S1.

The closest point on ellipsoid E1 is the point P given by:

P = M1'^-1 P'

**Closest point on ellipsoid E2**

The closest point on ellipsoid E2 is the point Q given by:

Q = M1'^-1 Q'

**Closest distance between ellipsoids E1 and E2**

The closest point on E1 w.r.t E2 is P and the closest point on E2 w.r.t E1 is Q. The shortest distance is |P - Q|

**How to Compute the Linear Function M**

A simple way to compute M is the following. Use the ellipsoid's semi-axes A1, A2 and A3 to create a 3x3 matrix U. Such that U has the vectors A1, A2 and A3 as columns.

Then scale the semi-axes A1 and A2 to have the same length to the semi-axes A3.Then create the matrix V auch that V has the new vector A1', A2' and A3' as columns.

Then we define the linear matrix system:

R U = V

Where R is a 3x3 (non-uniform-)scaling-rotation matrix.

We can solve for R by multiplying both sides of the equation by the inverse of U which is denoted by U^-1

R U U^-1 = V U^-1

Since U U^-1 is the identity matrix we get:

R = V U^+

Using R we define the affine transformation

M(x) = R (x - O) + O

Where O is the center of the ellipsoid.

We can use M to transform points to sphere space, such as ellipsoid center O, C, P and Q. But if we need to transform vectors such as A1, A2, A3 we have to use the simpler M:

M(x) = R x

Since A1, A2 and A3 are eigenvectors of R then R is not singular and has an inverse.  We define the inverse M as:

M^-1(x) = R^-1 (x - O) + O

And for vectors:

M^-1(x) = R^-1 x